# Redirecting routes with ui-route does not seem to take

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Ok so I created a project with Yeoman (angular-fullstack -> ui-route) and was able to change the main view directly to the login view. Now when you login successfully it should redirect to a desired route of my choosing.

My folder structure looks like this -> http://gyazo.com/a5e60dc2bc873c769f5926353829881c

I am trying to redirect to the month.html view. Here is the code for this (login.controller.js)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
  .controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $location) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.errors = {};

    $scope.login = function(form) {
      $scope.submitted = true;

      if(form.$valid) {
        Auth.login({
          email: $scope.user.email,
          password: $scope.user.password
        })
        .then( function() {
          // Logged in, redirect to home
          $location.path('/month');
        })
        .catch( function(err) {
          $scope.errors.other = err.message;
        });
      }
    };

  });
```

Code of calendar.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('zazzleToolPlannerApp')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('day', {
        url: '/day',
        templateUrl: 'app/calendar/day/day.html',
        controller: 'CalendarCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('week', {
        url: '/week',
        templateUrl: 'app/calendar/week/week.html',
        controller: 'CalendarCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      })
      .state('month', {
        url: '/month',
        templateUrl: 'app/calendar/month/month.html',
        controller: 'CalendarCtrl',
        authenticate: true
      });
  });
```

But when I login nothing happens although my console shows the login was successful -> http://gyazo.com/ddd066e0f399027d3cffa266f647a8e0

Comment: use `$state.go('month')` that will redirect safely..I'm assuming your route name is `month`

Comment: @PankajParkar: yes my routes are defined in calendar.js but its not working

Comment: @PankajParkar: never mind, got it to work

Comment: should I add an answer?

Comment: @PankajParkar: no its ok, thanks anyway

Comment: so if you don't mind you should add that answer..to close this issue..

Comment: I can only accept my answer as answered in 2 days...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83691/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-gy22).

Comment: Another time Pankaij Parkar. I am logging off to go sleep